# Como verificar no banco de dados se o cadastro já foi feito PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

Como faço pra verificar se o `id` do usuário já não tem registro no banco de dados e continuar com o `insert`?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $comment   = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comment']));

    $insert = "INSERT into tb_comment (id_mark, id_user, comment, up_c, down_c, rate, active) VALUES (:post_id, :idLogged, :comment, 0, 0, :star, NOW())";

    try {
        $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
        $result->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':star', $star, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();
        if($count>0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-sucess">
              <strong>Sucesso!</strong> avaliação cadastrada.
               </div>';
        }else{
          echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
              <strong>Erro ao cadastrar!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar a avaliação.
              </div>';
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer um `select id_user from tb_comment where id_user = idLogged` e checar se retorna alguma linha?

Comment: É então só q eu sou muito novato em PHP eu devo fazer o select dentro do if ou fora ?

Comment: Você quer checar se `ìdLogger` existe no banco antes de fazer o insert, correto?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do seu código, e pressupondo que todas as variáveis do seu `$_POST` já tenham sido capturados, faça um `select` e verifique através da função `fetchAll()`, se houve algum retorno:

```
$query = $conexao->prepare("select * from tb_comment where id_user = :idLogged");
$query->bindParam(':idLogged', $idLogged, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$retorno = $query->fetchAll();
if(count($retorno) > 0){
    //usuário está registrado
    //faça o insert aqui
else{
    //nenhum usuário encontrado 
}
```

**Nota:**

Foi usada a função `fecthAll()` ao invés da `rowCount()` devido a uma restrição desta ultima função, conforme descrito na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, **this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases** and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Ou seja, pode funcionar, mas não é garantido que funcione conforme o esperado. Mas caso queira testar, segue o mesmo código usando `rowCount()`:

```
 $retorno = $query->rowCount();
    if($retorno > 0){
        //usuário está registrado
        //faça o insert aqui
    else{
        //nenhum usuário encontrado 
    }
```

**Referências:**

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360451/php-pdo-fetchall-returns-empty-array

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: query

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on null in

Comment: @WilliamAlvares perdão, desantenção minha hehe, ja corrigi a variavel $query. vê se agora a consulta funciona.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.. Eu estava fazendo de um jeito aqui que não parecia ter nada de errado cara.. e ainda n sei por que n deu certo do jeito q fiz

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(session_id() == '') {
    // checka se tem sessão, se a não tiver sessão , inicia a session
    session_start();
} 

 $checkuser = $_POST['ID'];


    $dados = $conexao_pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM user WHERE id = ?');
$dados->bindParam(1, $checkuser);
$dados->execute();
if ($dados->rowCount() > 0) {
  $linha = $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  //id não ok
  $_SESSION["checkid"] = "0";

  }else{
     $_SESSION["checkid"] = "1";
     //id ok

  }

    //sessão 0 o id já ta cadastrado e nao pode cadastrar sessão 1 usuário pode cadastrar com id
```

DEPOIS VOCÊ COMPARA COM A SESSION

```
if($_SESSION['checkid'] >= 1)  {
            // o id esta disponivel
            $id = $_POST["ID"];


            } else {
                //destroi sessão pois o id não está disponivel 
                $_POST["id"] = "";
                unset($_SESSION['checkid']); 

            }
?>
```